# Is there any possibility to go with a/c compressor, repair/overhauling instead of moving with replacement

Tags: hvac

Is there any possibility to go with a/c compressor, repair/overhauling instead of moving with replacement. Then, what are the parts we can go ahead with change of parts of a compressor.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-build a compressor, but can you source all the items you need to replace? Valves, seals etc

Then do you have any of the special tooling that may be required?

That is why it is usually more cost-effective to purchase a re-furbished unit where you return the old one in part-exchange.